# Read analog signal over the SPI bus using MCP3201 ADC and Arduino Uno

Tags: adc

It is possible to use the SPI bus when the **Vref** of MCP3201 ADC is 2.5V?
On the setup i just finished, I used two linear regulators: **5V -> 3.3V** to power the *MCP602* op-amps and *MCP3201* ADC, and another one **5v -> 2.5V** for the Vref.
Everyone recommends to connect the Vref from MCP3201 to Arduino's 5V but this does not apply in my case.
[image]

[image]

The green connector is connected to **GND** and ADC's **Dout** where the measured voltage fluctuates from 0.180V when i touch the sensor and his shield, to 0.6V when i'm not touching those parts.
I have no ideea if this is a normal behaviour but everything looks fine to me. 
Voltage measured at the output of A4 ( MCP3201 +IN ) is **0.85V** and the current **Iref** is **1mA**(through the yellow jumper) as they recommend.

Sorry if these details are a bit off-topic but i think they are relevant to the ADC role in this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to use the SPI bus when the Vref of MCP3201 ADC is 2.5V?

Of course it is. V<sub>REF</sub> is purely a reference voltage for taking measurements. It has no other role.

If you look at the functional block diagram from the datasheet:

[image]

You can plainly see that V<sub>REF</sub> is only connected to the DAC that is used as part of the SAR feedback loop. Everything else is fed from V<sub>DD</sub>

Comment: Now it makes sense. So *Dout*, *CLK*, *CS* and *GND* should be the only pins connected to Arduino for SPI communication. **CS->pin9**, **Dout->pin12**, **CLK->pin13** and **GND->GND**. 
Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this aspect. I came from web development so Arduino, C++ and electronics are new and beautiful territories for me.